# How to check if an element contains more separate words in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a list of items/words:

```
<results>
  <string>
    <part>Downs</part>
    <part>1957</part>
  </string>
  <string>
    <part>Carmines</part>
    <part>Huckfeldt</part>
    <part>1996</part>
  </string>
</results>
```

In a document, I need to search for paragraphs containing all `parts` of a particular `string` at once.

For me, it seems a bit tricky because I need to iterate over `results` items and compare all of them to every paragraph.

Something like:

```
for $part in $results//part
let $paragraph := $doc//p[contains(., $part)]
return
    $paragraph
```

This returns all paragraphs containing one or more words from every `string`. It is not possible to group them because they are always unique in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [quantified expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-quantified-expressions) to express exactly what you want:

```
for $p in $doc//p
where
  some $string in $results//string
  satisfies (
    every $part in $string/part
    satisfies contains($p, $part)
  )
return $p
```

Here's a shorter version:

```
for $p in $doc//p
where $results//string[every $part in ./part satisfies contains($p, $part)]
return $p
```

And finally a short but cryptic version without quantified expressions:

```
for $p in $doc//p
where $results//string[not(part[not(contains($p, .))])]
return $p
```

It returns all paragraphs for which there is a string so that **none** of its parts is **not** contained in the paragraph. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day :) Yes, I am not surprised by the last solution. It is typically sort of by a mathematician!